# d3.js - force - how can I configure the force to place each nodes to grow farther away from the origin nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am studying d3.js and would like to know if it is possible to grow the nodes outward as generation of nodes goes down.

For example, in example below, I am forcing the location of node 0.

I would like to place the nodes so child nodes 1,2,3,4 are surrounding node 0, and grand child nodes 5,6,7,8 are placed at the outskirts of nodes 1,2,3,4 farther and farther away from node 0.

In the example below, the grandchild nodes 5,7 are closer to node 0 than child nodes.

Would it be possible to achieve what I am looking for?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 v5 force simulation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="600" height="400"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var nodesData = [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ]

  var linksData = [
    { "source": 0, "target": 1 },
    { "source": 0, "target": 2 },
    { "source": 0, "target": 3 },
    { "source": 0, "target": 4 },
    { "source": 1, "target": 5 },
    { "source": 1, "target": 6 },
    { "source": 1, "target": 7 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 8 }
  ]

  var link = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(linksData)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke", "black");

  var node = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodesData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .attr("fill", "LightSalmon");

    const svg = d3.select("svg");
    const sWidth = +svg.attr("width");
    const sHeight = +svg.attr("height");

    nodesData[0].fx = sWidth / 2;
    nodesData[0].fy = sHeight / 2;

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide()
                        .radius((d)=>{return 10})
                        .strength(1.0)
                        .iterations(1))
    .force("x", d3.forceX().strength(0.7))
    .force("y", d3.forceY().strength(0.7))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink())
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-6000))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(sWidth/2, sHeight/2));

  simulation
    .nodes(nodesData)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(linksData);

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-force) there is a distance method you can pass to force a fixed length for the links. Although you will probably need to play with other values to accomplish exactly the kind of equilibrium you are after.

```
.distance(function(d) {return d.distance;})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 v5 force simulation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="600" height="400"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var nodesData = [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ]

  var linksData = [
    { "source": 0, "target": 1 },
    { "source": 0, "target": 2 },
    { "source": 0, "target": 3 },
    { "source": 0, "target": 4 },
    { "source": 1, "target": 5 },
    { "source": 1, "target": 6 },
    { "source": 1, "target": 7 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 8 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 9 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 10 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 11 }
  ]

  var link = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(linksData)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke", "black");

  var node = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodesData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .attr("fill", "LightSalmon");

    const svg = d3.select("svg");
    const sWidth = +svg.attr("width");
    const sHeight = +svg.attr("height");

    nodesData[0].fx = sWidth / 2;
    nodesData[0].fy = sHeight / 2;

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide()
                        .radius(40)
                        .strength(1)
                        .iterations(1))
    .force("x", d3.forceX().strength(0))
    .force("y", d3.forceY().strength(0))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(function(d) {return 30;}))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(0))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(sWidth/2, sHeight/2));

  simulation
    .nodes(nodesData)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(linksData);

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but even in your example, the grand-child nodes 8,9 are closer than one of the child (either 3 or 4) https://imgur.com/vFkRe7R

Comment: My bad. I edited the answer, I think that's what we were looking for.

Comment: Thanks again, feel bad for being picky, but grandchild still closer than some of the children. I would like to grow farther and farther as generation goes by https://imgur.com/HV12yKh

Comment: I see, don't worry. Force layout is more of a physical system than a pure geometric one, I don't think that can be done without calculating and fixing each individual item, but I will look further into it when I have the chance

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I just would like to have view basically like a Tree growth visible from above. Data structural Tree never goes "up" as the generation goes down. Similarly I wanted this force graph to be growing outward.